# Why aren't all TextViews and their states being retained?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-view

I'm still new to Android (and coding) and this is my first time working with Swipe views, i.e. ViewPagers and adapters. My activity has 3 fragments. When I move from Fragment A to Fragment B, all is fine. But when I move to Fragment C, `onStop` gets called for Fragment A. When I return to Fragment A, all of my views have been restored except for a few. The `EditText` views are fine, but other views have problems...

- I have a couple of TextViews that I enable/disable. These states are not retained.
- Other TextViews can be visible/invisible. These states are not retained.
- I don't believe the TextView texts are being retained either.

It was my impression that `onSaveInstanceState` saves views. Do I have to save these states manually? Since these are `Fragments`, should that be done through `arguments`?

Here is my Fragment `onCreateView`

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.activity_grade_calculator, container, false);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if(args.containsKey(PERSISTENT_FIRSTLOAD_BUNDLE_KEY)) {
        firstLoad = args.getBoolean(PERSISTENT_FIRSTLOAD_BUNDLE_KEY);
    }
    context = this.getActivity();

    if(firstLoad) {
        bindAll();
        setInitialViews();  
        setListeners();
    }
    firstLoad = false;
    return rootView;
}
```

Here is `MyPagerAdapter`

```
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int i) {
    //System.out.println("We are trying to get item " + i);
    switch(i) {
        case 0:
            Fragment fragment = new FinalCalcFragment();
            return fragment;
        case 1:
            Fragment fragment1 = new NewGradeCalcFragment();
            return fragment1;
        case 2:
            Fragment fragment3 = new NewGradeCalcFragment();
            return fragment3;
        default:
            return null;
    }

}
```

Here are some `TextView`s that are not behaving nicely.

```
<TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_grade_calc_forgrade"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/tv_grade_calc_forgrade" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_grade_calc_ifscore"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/radioGroup1"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:text="@string/tv_grade_calc_ifscore" />

             <TextView
                 android:id="@+id/tv_grade_calc_result"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_below="@id/tv_grade_calc_ifscore"
                 android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                 android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
                 android:textSize="28sp" />
```

Edit: Btw, I've played around with both `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. I don't fully understand what they do differently, but neither seem to give me what I want.

Comment: FragmentStatePagerAdapter is preferable in your case because it saves the state of your Fragments.

Comment: Thanks, although it still doesn't save the TextViews like I'd like.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ViewPager Fragments getting destroyed over time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857420/viewpager-fragments-getting-destroyed-over-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only have those three `Fragments` in your `ViewPager`, you can define a minimum number of `Fragments` that are always being kept in memory at one time by using the method `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(value);` 
The default value is 1. That is the reason your Fragment A state is being lost when you swipe to Fragment C. If you increase this value to 2, that will not happen, as the `ViewPager` will always keep the state of two `Fragments` (ahead or before) your current showing `Fragment`.

Comment: Well, that did it! Thanks! I'll also look into manually saving these when my fragment is stopped so that I don't hit any problems down the road.

Answer (score 1):

The viewpager keeps only one page in advance. When you reach fragment C, the fragment A is released.

The fragment lifecycle is similar to the activity lifecycle, and a fragment can be stopped when it's not used anymore. You should be prepared for this.

Like for activities, you need to manually save the state in [`onSaveInstanceState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onSaveInstanceState(android.os.Bundle)) and restore the state later.

Comment: Does that mean that--although `EditText`s have their states saved--the `TextView`s won't be retained? What are the rules regarding this? I suppose I can save the TextView states if I need to.

Comment: Indeed, you should keep the state of the Views (visiblility/enabled/etc) yourself and restore it appropriately (for instance in `onCreate` or in `onCreateView`).

Comment: `EditText` already natively saves it's data (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553634/fragment-automatically-saving-and-restoring-state-of-edittexts) but I'd be surprised if they also save their visibility.